# localize iOS app based on MCC MNC

Tags: ios, localization, mcc

I'm looking for a way to based the localization of my iOS app, on the MCC or MNC.
I already know how to do it with the language/region of the device, but I was wondering if it possible to localize with the carrier too.
It is possible on Android, so maybe it is possible on iOS

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. You can get the SIM cards MCC and MNC with [Core Telephony - CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCarrier).

But if the user is roaming you will still get the same MCC and MNC, since this is based SIM card and not the network.

Also you will need to check if Core Telephony is available in the device since not all device have cellular connectivity or a SIM card installed.

Comment: thanks rckoenes, I've already a list of MCC/MNC, and the app is on iPhone only for now. But Is there a way to tell the app to switch to a particular assets based on the MCC ? If I use AT&T for example, I want to see their logo, but if my friend are using Verizon, they want to see Verizon's logo